# Scaling an Entity Framework Application / Multiple Apps hitting the same database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

I have a application that has been programmed with MVC/EF Code First. It does a lot of server side processing and is pretty resource intensive.

I know how to set up load balancing, but, I want to know if scaling an EF application is as simple as provisioning a new server, deploying the application and pointing to the DB cluster - or are there any issues I will face with regards to multiple EF applications hitting the same database server?

I can't seem to find any advice/guides for this and I am worrying I made the wrong choice by choosing EF over something simpler/more straight forward!

Comment: For performance: it depends where the bottleneck is. If you've got one query that's particularly expensive to run and it needs to run multiple times then spreading those executions across multiple DB instances might be the way to go. But if you have a lot of lightweight queries and most of time is spent inside your application then a DB cluster won't help. If you haven't done so, try profiling your application and seeing what % of time is spent in your code vs. external code vs. external resources (database, web service calls).

Comment: But at a more fundamental level, one of the complexities of dealing with multiple instances of an MVC application is state management. E.g. If you keep some information about the next page request in memory, but the user gets load balanced onto another server... How does that server know about what the first server's got in memory?

Comment: @te.speot.is - The problem is pretty much I/O related... The application isn't much more than a API... I have clients that send large requests containing a lot of data and my application has to process/sort/filter before storing in the back end DB... I need to support many more clients and just want to learn about EF scaling / I am worried what will happen when both front ends need to write to the same table.

Comment: On top of that, I ideally want to build some "extra" support applications that hook in to the same DB... and, I am just not sure how EF will handle multiple apps to the same DB.... Wondering if I should go down to Linq where at least I know how things will work :/

Answer (score 3):

> ... issues ... regards to multiple EF applications hitting the same database server?

Rewind a bit to the fact that your application is an ASP .NET MVC based application. Having multiple instances of it is probably going to raise the spectre of state management.

MSDN has a pretty good introduction to [why this is an issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx):

> HTTP is a stateless protocol. This means that a Web server treats each HTTP request for a page as an independent request. The server retains no knowledge of variable values that were used during previous requests. ASP.NET session state identifies requests from the same browser during a limited time window as a session, and provides a way to persist variable values for the duration of that session. By default, ASP.NET session state is enabled for all ASP.NET applications.
>
> Alternatives to session state include the following:
>
> - Application state, which stores variables that can be accessed by all users of an ASP.NET application.

This point is an extremely common way of storing state, but breaks down when there's multiple instances of an application involved (the state is "visible" to only one of the instances).

Typically this is worked around by using either the `StateServer` or `SQLServer` value of `SessionStateMode`. The same article provides a pretty good summary of each option (emphasis mine).

> - `StateServer` mode, which stores session state in a separate process called the ASP.NET state service. This ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is restarted **and also makes session state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm**.
> - `SQLServer` mode stores session state in a SQL Server database. This ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is restarted **and also makes session state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm**.

If your application is stateless, this is a moot point.

> I am worrying I made the wrong choice by choosing EF

As far as issues with multiple instances of your application accessing a database go, you're going to have issues with any sort of data access technology.

Here's the basic scenario: let's say your application sends welcome emails to users on a schedule.

Given the table `Users`:

```
UserId | Email           | WelcomeLetterSent
-------+-----------------+------------------
     1 | user@domain.com | 0
```

And some psuedo-code:

```
foreach (var user in _context.Users.Where(u => !u.WelcomeLetterSent))
{
    SendEmailForUser(user);
    user.WelcomeLetterSent = true;
}

_context.SaveChanges();
```

There's a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) where both instance one and instance two of your application might simultaneously evaluate `_context.Users.Where(...)` before either of them has the chance to set `WelcomeLetterSent = true` and call `SaveChanges`. In this case, two welcome emails might get sent to each user instead of one.

Concurrency can be an insidious thing. There's a primer on managing concurrency with the Entity Framework over [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), but this is only the tip of the iceberg.

The answer to your question? It depends on what your application does :)

> On top of that, I ideally want to build some "extra" support applications that hook in to the same DB... and, I am just not sure how EF will handle multiple apps to the same DB....

If your application can tolerate multiple instances of itself accessing one database, then it's usually not a stretch to make these "support applications" play nicely. It's not much different whether the concurrency is from multiple instances of one application or multiple applications with one instance each.

Comment: You haven't mentioned EF Migrations. How can you perform migrations without taking all the servers down?

Comment: @Kugel Take 'em all down. OP doesn't have a requirement for 100% availability.